# Instance member 'webView' cannot be used on type 'MyWebView(UIview)'

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am creating one SDK to get the url from user and load. So ai m creating my own class with WKWebview. But i am getting few issues about `Instance member 'webView' cannot be used on type 'MyWebView(UIview)'`

Code :

```
import Foundation
import WebKit

public class MyWebView: UIView, WKNavigationDelegate {

    // initialize the view
     var webView: WKWebView!
    
    // load the view
    private func loadView() {
        webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
    }
    
    // get the url and load the page
    public static func loadUrl(Url: String) {
        MyWebView.webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: Url)!))
    }
    
    
    
}
```

In my loadUrl, what ever user sending i need to use that url and load the url. Same in my view controller will look like :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var webView: MyWebView!
    
    override func loadView() {
        view = webView
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `loadUrl` function should not be static, since it needs access to an instance property, `webView`. Making the function non-static solves the issue.

Also a couple of minor improvements: don't force unwrap the `URL` init, since with an incorrect input that will crash. Use optional binding to safely unwrap it instead. I'd also suggest renaming the input argument label on `loadUrl`, since there's no point in having to right out `loadUrl(Url:)` every time you call the func, `loadUrl(` reads more naturally.

```
public func loadUrl(_ urlString: String) {
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
}
```

Comment: `public func passUrl(url: String) {
        guard let url = URL(string: url) else { return }
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "URL", options: .new, context: nil)
    }`

Comment: I can able to call in my view controller. But its getting crash like `webView.passUrl(url: "https://www.swiggy.com")`. Crash : `Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file <EXPR>, line 7`

Comment: Any help for here ? 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63150713/getting-black-screen-in-load-of-webview-url-from-my-own-class

Comment: @kumarbarian have a look at [Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu), it explains pretty much all possible causes of that crash (and their fixes as well)

Comment: Crash i have fixed. But i am getting some black screen on load the URL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63150713/getting-black-screen-in-load-of-webview-url-from-my-own-class