# How to fix black screen in load of webview url from my own class

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am creating one SDK to get the url from user and load. So ai m creating my own class with `WKWebview`. But i am getting few issues about Instance member `webView` cannot be used on type `MyWebView(UIview)`

My code :

```
import Foundation
import WebKit

public class MyWebView: UIView, WKNavigationDelegate {

    // initialize the view
     var webView: WKWebView!

    // get the url and load the page
    public func passUrl(url: String) {
        guard let url = URL(string: url) else { return }
        webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "URL", options: .new, context: nil)
    }
    
    // Observe value
    override public func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if let key = change?[NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey] {
            print("URL Changes: \(key)")
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "URL Changed", message: "\(key)", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default, handler: nil))
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    
}
```

My view controller :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var webView =  MyWebView()
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view = webView
        webView.passUrl(url: "https://www.swiggy.com")
    }
}
```

When i run, i am getting my screen as black. Not sure what i am doing wong. Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code. Tested and working for me.
**MyWebView Class**

```
import Foundation
import WebKit

public class MyWebView: UIView, WKNavigationDelegate {

// initialize the view
let view: WKWebView = {
    let view = WKWebView()
    return view
}()

// get the url and load the page
public func passUrl(url: String) {
    guard let url = URL(string: url) else { return }
    view.navigationDelegate = self
    view.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    view.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
    view.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "URL", options: .new, context: nil)
}

// Observe value
override public func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if let key = change?[NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey] {
        print("URL Changes: \(key)")
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "URL Changed", message: "\(key)", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default, handler: nil))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

public override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupView()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

private func setupView() {
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    addSubview(view)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
        view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
        view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
        view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
    ])
}
}
```

**ViewController Class**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var webView =  MyWebView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    webView.passUrl(url: "https://www.swiggy.com")
}

override func loadView() {
    view = webView
}
}
```

Check it if this does not fix the problem let me know.

Comment: i have one doubt. In same mywebview class i need to call some alamofire request and use that response value as alert. No related to my view controller. If i install alamofire , and use it in mywebview class. When i create an SDK, Should user need to install alamofire pod ?

Comment: You can install alamofire and make different class for alamofire and you can call alamofire request in ViewController. And my question is who's the user you're talking about?

Comment: Let say, I am creating one SDK which will show the some web view URL. So I am creating my own class and using it in my view controller. Till this I have done. But I need to call one alamofire api in my own class and show some alert once web view loaded. This alamofire is noting related to my view controller. When ever I get url from my view controller, I need to call my alamofire api. 

My doubt is ,

1. Should I need to install pod in my own class project and then need to create an SDK
2. Or I will ask user to import alamofire and install using pod to their project ?

Comment: Install alamofire pod and import alamofire.

Comment: Should i tell to user (who is using my SDK) to install alamofire pod and import alamofire. Or i should install alamofire pod and import alamofire and then i need to create SDK totally ?

Comment: yes tell user to install alamofire and import alamofire

Comment: @ Habin Lama In that case i need to import the alamofire in my webview class also right ?.  with that only i need to create SDK right ?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't assign your web view to the main view in the view controller. Try to add it as a subview:

```swift
webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(webView)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
    webView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
    webView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
    webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
])
```

Update the passUrl ass follows:

```swift
public func passUrl(url: String) {
    guard let url = URL(string: url) else { return }
    webView = WKWebView()
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
    webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "URL", options: .new, context: nil)
        
    webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    addSubview(webView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
        webView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
        webView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
        webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
    ])
}
```

This way you should see the web page.

Since you can only call the passUrl method once, otherwise it will continue to create web views, and add them to the view hierarchy, I would update the MyWebView class like this:

```swift
public class MyWebView: UIView, WKNavigationDelegate {

    // initialize the view
    var webView: WKWebView!
    
    // override the init to be able to create and add to the view only one instance of the WKWebView
    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "URL", options: .new, context: nil)
        
        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(webView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            webView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            webView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
        ])
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    // get the url and load the page
    public func passUrl(url: String) {
        guard let url = URL(string: url) else { return }
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    }
    
    // Observe value
    override public func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if let key = change?[NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey] {
            print("URL Changes: \(key)")
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "URL Changed", message: "\(key)", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default, handler: nil))
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

I tried it on the project you posted and it works.

[image]

Comment: this is in my view controller or in mywebview class ?

Comment: It is instead of view = webView

Comment: i attched my sample project here https://www.dropbox.com/s/co0wgrbp23nttwb/UrlSdk.zip?dl=0

Comment: Oh yes, I missed that. The subview you created, generates the web view, but it doesn’t add it to the view. I will update my answer.

Comment: in my both view controller and in mywebview class ,. I have did like this  `webView = MyWebView()` creating new instance like this. Is this the correct way or am i doing it wrong

Comment: Check the answer ;)

Comment: What is the difference, dont need to specify view ?. I giving some error `Use of unresolved identifier 'topAnchor'`